# Web scraping BeautifulSoup find_all doesn't work on APEC

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[the source code of the page is as in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onawy.png)

I want to findall div class container-result but it doesn't work I get an empty list

my code :
`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString, Tag
import requests
import urllib.request
url = "https://www.apec.fr/candidat/recherche-emploi.html/emploi?page="
for page in range(0,10,1):
    r = requests.get(url + str(page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser")
    ancher = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'container-result'})
print(ancher)
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the web page is rendered by javascript, requests / BeautifulSoup will not be able to retrieve DOM elements needed as they're added after some time whilst page is being rendered. You could try to use selenium for this purpose, here is an example:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

# delay for selenium web driver wait
DELAY = 30

# create selenium driver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
#chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('<<PATH TO chromedriver>>', options=chrome_options)

# iterate over pages
for page in range(0, 10, 1):
    
    # open web page
    driver.get(f'https://www.apec.fr/candidat/recherche-emploi.html/emploi?page={page}')
    
    # wait for element with class 'container-result' to be added
    container_result = WebDriverWait(driver, DELAY).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "container-result")))
    # scroll to container-result
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", container_result)
    # get source HTML of the container-result element
    source = container_result.get_attribute('innerHTML')
    # print source
    print(source)
    # here you can continue work with the source variable either using selenium API or using BeautifulSoup API:
    # soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")

# quit webdriver    
driver.quit()
```